# SignalR not firing OnDisconnected

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

The problem:
SignalR is not firing `OnDisconnected` on my webserver. It is very simple, but is not firing. I have tried:

- Closing browser window
- Navigating away
- Reloading
- Firing stop() on the SignalR-connection from client side.

---

```
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled) {
    LogUtil.LogInfo("Disconn");
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

I am using SignalR 2.2.0.0 and `OnConnected` is working just fine. 
I have tried recommendations of doing at last one client call to make sure the connection is up and running. 
 
I have searched all forums, SO, GIT etc etc and nothing solves my issue.

Comment: I have the same version, but it takes around 40 seconds to disconnect. (The event does fire after 40 seconds.) The reason has something to do with a feature that tries to reconnect to user in case of slow network - I can't remember it well though. Did you wait for sufficient time after closing the browser? Btw, which browser are you using?

Comment: I have waited up to 30 minutes. Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113

Comment: I have chrome 60 as well. Closing the tab, reloading it or invoking stop on client should be adequate. Can you post the hub.connect and hub.stop related code? Also, try adding `stateChanged` event on the client and see its logs, in case something odd is going on.

Comment: SignalR state changed from: disconnected to: connecting ->
SignalR state changed from: connecting to: connected -> 
onmessage { "msg": "Users online: 2" } ->
 ->
--Pressing reload ->
SignalR state changed from: connected to: disconnected ->
SignalR state changed from: disconnected to: connecting ->
SignalR state changed from: connecting to: connected

Comment: hmm that is as expected... so doesn't it fire the server event when the state changes to disconnected?

Comment: Yes, on client looks good. Server still no response. No log, no nothing

Comment: Are you sure that logging is fine? If you're running it locally, how about setting a breakpoint and waiting for it to be hit? Also try (Ctrl + D) + (Ctrl + E) -> Enable all CLR exceptions to ensure that there is no rogue exception in between.

Comment: I replaced with System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/connectionState.txt"), "Disconnected " + Context.ConnectionId); in both both event, for connecting, and disconnectiong and same as before, works for connecting.

Comment: I can't think of anything else at the moment. Perhaps you could open a case with Microsoft, or report an issue on their Git repo. Or, you could open a bounty in a couple of days...

Comment: Enable tracing on Signalr server and see if you can get something out of it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing

Comment: SignalR: Window unloading, stopping the connection.
SignalR: Stopping connection.
SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = false.
SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.

So it seems as client side does its job

Comment: I got the tracing running, and get
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : CloseSocket()
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Information: 0 : Abort()
SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartBeat Information: 0 : Removing connection )
SignalR.HubDispatcher Information: 0 : Error creating Hub ChatHub. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
SignalR.Transports.WebSocketTransport Verbose: 0 : DrainWrites()

So i get error right in the removing disconnecting, but no stacktrace no nothing

Comment: Turns out by the logging it failed to create the hub on disconnect. I cleared all code and not it works somehow.

Comment: @Pochen maybe you should update your question or add an answer yourself then...

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with this also, I had to use LongPolling. There also isn't any current example of disconnect/reconnect javascript code I could find.

Here's my code (exclude shoddy html included for completeness):

```js
<hr />

<style>
 table { table-layout: fixed; }
 table th, table td { overflow: hidden; }
</style>

<div id="logs">
    <table id="logTable" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20%">Time</th>
                <th style="width: 5%">Level</th>
                <th>Message</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/signalr-clientES5-1.0.0-alpha2-final.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // global refs
    var transportType;
    var logger;
    var loggingHub;
    var loggingConnection;

    function prependLogRow(logEvent) {
        var d = new Date(logEvent.timeStamp); //.ToString("dd/MM H:mm:ss");
        var m = logEvent.message;
        var s = "<tr><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + logEvent.level + "</td><td>" + m + "</td></tr>";
        $("#logTable tbody").prepend(s);

        var rowCount = $('#logTable tr').length;
        if (rowCount > 500) {
            $("#logTable").find("tr:gt(250)").remove();
        }
    };

    function createLogEvent(message) {
        var logEvent = {};
        logEvent.timeStamp = new Date();
        logEvent.level = 'Info';
        logEvent.message = message;
        return logEvent;
    };

    function bindEvents(logger) {

        logger.connection.onclose = (e) => {
            var logEvent = createLogEvent('Logger disconnected. Retrying...');
            prependLogRow(logEvent);
            setTimeout(function () 
            {
                transportType = signalR.TransportType.LongPolling; //;WebSockets
                logger = new signalR.ConsoleLogger(signalR.LogLevel.Trace);
                loggingHub = new signalR.HttpConnection(`https://${document.location.host}/signalr`, { transport: transportType, logger: logger });
                loggingConnection = new signalR.HubConnection(loggingHub, logger);
                bindEvents(loggingConnection);
                var logEvent = createLogEvent('Logger reconnected.');
                prependLogRow(logEvent);
            }, 1000); // Restart connection after a second.
        };

        logger.on('Log', (logEvent) => {
            prependLogRow(logEvent);
        });

        logger.start().catch(err => {
            console.log('connection error');
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

        transportType = signalR.TransportType.LongPolling; //;WebSockets
        logger = new signalR.ConsoleLogger(signalR.LogLevel.Trace);
        loggingHub = new signalR.HttpConnection(`https://${document.location.host}/signalr`, { transport: transportType, logger: logger });
        loggingConnection = new signalR.HubConnection(loggingHub, logger);

        bindEvents(loggingConnection);

        var logEvent = createLogEvent('Logger loaded. Please wait...');
        prependLogRow(logEvent);
    })
</script>
```

this code feels wrong, but was the only iteration i could get to work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with logging in OnDisconnect not functioning correctly.  Like you, I figured that the OnDisconnect method was not being invoked.

But it turns out I was assuming that HttpContext.Current was available.  (My logger uses it to pull some state information from the session.)  When you think about it, expecting a current context doesn't make sense.  You are disconnecting, after all!  A null pointer exception was being thrown for HttpContext.Current, but I couldn't see it.

Once I removed the dependency on HttpContext.Current, I was able to log disconnects and send out alert emails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed at least one chat.client.broadcast method to make it work ... otherwise, it would fire any other event but OnDisconnected method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a hub I used only to call Server methods.

When I subscribed the javascript proxy client **to at least one** Server hub event, OnDisconnected method started firing.

```
hubProxy.on('myEvent', myHandler);
```